# Disable multiple computer account from txt

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
$Computers = Get-Content c:\temp\computers.txt

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $ADComputer = $null
    $ADComputer = Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties Description

    if ($ADComputer) {
        Add-Content C:\temp\computers.log -Value "Found $Computer, disabling"
        Set-ADComputer $ADComputer -Description "Computer Disabled on $(Get-Date)" -Enabled $false
    } else {
        Add-Content C:\temp\computers.log -Value "$Computer not in Active Directory"
    }
}
```

Can someone verify whether above code is correct?
Above code suppose to:

- disable multiple computers, read from txt file.
- Edit description of the disabled computers.
- create log file for the result.

Customer don't have any testing environment that we can test. So I just don't want to risk anything.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Try with only one Computer in the text file first and check AD. Easy to reverse if it didn't work.

Comment: To reverse i just edit below line right ? change from false to true

Set-ADComputer $ADComputer -Description "Computer Disabled on $(Get-Date)" -Enabled $true

Comment: When you reverse to `Enabled`, I would also adjust the `-Description` to either be an empty string or to something like "Computer Enabled on $(Get-Date)". You can always test with just one machine and look in ADUC to see if it does what you want before going through a whole bunch of computers.

Comment: You don't need a test environment for testing things like this. Simply create a test computer account and run your code with just that account in the input file. You can also use the chicken-switch (`-WhatIf`) so that a cmdlet will only display what it *would* do without actually doing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code is working fine. So i am posting this as answer.

```
$Computers = Get-Content c:\temp\computers.txt

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $ADComputer = $null
    $ADComputer = Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties Description

    if ($ADComputer) {
        Add-Content C:\temp\computers.log -Value "Found $Computer, disabling"
        Set-ADComputer $ADComputer -Description "Computer Disabled on $(Get-Date)" -Enabled $false
    } else {
        Add-Content C:\temp\computers.log -Value "$Computer not in Active Directory"
    }
}
```